# redux-next-wrapper with supabase v2 ssr

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, supabase

Before `supabase` V2 I got my data and stored in with redux like this:

`supabase` V2 broke unfortunately some functionality with `redux-next-wrapper`

```
export const getServerSideProps = wrapper.getServerSideProps(
  (store) => async ({ req }) => {
    const { user } = await supabase.auth.api.getUserByCookie(req);
    if (user === null) {
      return {
        redirect: {
          permanent: false,
          destination: "/auth",
        },
        props: {},
      };
    }
    if (user) {
      async function getData() {
        let { data, error, status } = await supabase
          .from("table")
          .select(`id`)
          .eq("id", user.id);
        store.dispatch(writeUserData(data));
        return data;
      }

      return {
        props: {
          data: await getData(),
        },
      };
    }
  }
);
```

Any ideas how I can achieve the same functionality with `withPageAuth()`?

```
export const getServerSideProps = withPageAuth({
  redirectTo: '/foo',
  async getServerSideProps (ctx, supabase) {
    // Access the user object
    const {
      data: { user }
    } = await supabase.auth.getUser()

    return { props: { id: user?.id } }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be similar to what you already have except that the redirect is handled by the `withPageAuth` already.

```
export const getServerSideProps = withPageAuth({
  redirectTo: '/auth',
  async getServerSideProps (ctx, supabase) {
    // Access the user object
    const {
      data: { user }
    } = await supabase.auth.getUser()

    let { data, error, status } = await supabase
      .from("table")
      .select(`id`)
      .eq("id", user.id);
    store.dispatch(writeUserData(data));

    return { props: { data } }
  }
})
```

Comment: But where to define the store?

Comment: Redux store is a global store so you would just import it into the file you are using this.